# Shibboleth SP - NameID attribute map

Tags: coldfusion, saml, iis-8, shibboleth

I am just learning Shibboleth SP and I have run into an issue where I cannot read the NameID from the SAML Response I receive from our corporate IdP.  The only "attribute" they have configured for me is the NameID which holds the username in our AD.  They do not add it as an attribute, but rather in the subject.  Below is the portion of the SAML response containing the NameID.

```
<Subject>
    <NameID>XXXXXX</NameID>
    <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_cbedab7210959e0d00294c557c648eb5"
                                     NotOnOrAfter="2017-05-18T21:15:24.776Z"
                                     Recipient="https://xxxxxx.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST"
                                     />
    </SubjectConfirmation>
</Subject>
```

How can I extract this simple value? I have not found an example entry in the attribute-map.xml that seems to fit the bill.

I am using IIS 8.5 and ColdFusion.

Comment: This looks like a job for `parsexml()`. See: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/xmlparse.html

Comment: I am familiar with parsing XML documents with CF (in fact I was doing that prior to trying Shibboleth), but I don't think that is the solution here.  Shibboleth intercepts the SAML response via an ISAPI filter, so I'm not sure I can even get the XML document after that.  I should be able to add an item to the attribute-map.xml file to retrieve the value.

Comment: Updated original post with my solution.

Comment: FYI - Rolled back to original version since the solution was already moved to an "answer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got the attribute to map using the following.  In my case, I had replaced SAML:1.1 with SAML2.  I assume the NameID is part of the SAML:1.1 spec.

```
<Attribute name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" id="NameID">
    <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="NameIDAttributeDecoder" formatter="$Name" defaultQualifiers="true"/>
</Attribute>
```